# How to backup my Google Drive for Windows files onto an external backup drive

Tags: windows-10, backup, external-hard-drive, google-drive-file-stream, google-backup-and-sync

I'm on Windows 10, and trying to organise my file system and backups. I would like to have all of my "main" files (documents, etc.) on Google Drive, so I can access them across different computers and my Android phone. However, this is posing a problem when it comes to backups. If the files I use most often are on Google drive, it would be prudent to back them up onto an external hard drive. Preferably, this would be automatic (e.g. using a backup software) so I'm more likely to do it.

As you all no doubt know, there are two options for Google cloud storage: *Backup and Sync*, which syncs a local "Google Drive" folder with the cloud, and *Google Drive for Windows*, which replaced File Stream, and streams files from your Google Drive onto your computer as needed. It would be easy to use Backup and Sync as the folder is on `C:` and can be backed up by any backup software...too easy. See, [Google is phasing out Backup and Sync](https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/02/04/googles-terrible-drive-desktop-client-will-soon-be-replaced-by-g-suite-version/) by the end of this year, and I don't want to go through the effort of setting everything up and then having to change everything in six month's time.

So, Google Drive for Windows it is, right? Well, the problem is getting the damn thing to backup. The files are accessed on `G:` drive by default, which is not a network drive, but isn't a local drive either. So my backup software (I'm currently using Veeam) doesn't recognise that it exists, but from what I've seen this isn't a problem specific to this particular program. I've tried searching everywhere, but either it's impossible or my google-fu skills aren't up to par.

Of course, I could switch to OneDrive, or Dropbox, but they don't offer any mid-tier options for pricing like Google Drive's 100 GB. Because I'm on a budget, that's ruled out.

It seems like the only alternative is to manually copy-paste my files onto the backup drive every time I want to do a backup. I would try to automate this with a bash script or similiar using WSL, but I can't even access my files that way. I can navigate to `/mnt/g`, but it shows up as a totally empty directory.

So, I would appreciate if the wisdom of the community can point me to a better idea than "copy all my files every [time interval] to the backup drive", or let me know if I am missing an obvious solution!